# Post quantum zkSNARK?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, quantum-cryptography, post-quantum-cryptography

*Do there exist any zkSNARK constructions that are based on post quantum cryptography?*

The encryption scheme used in the zkSNARK that is employed in Zcash for instance uses an encryption scheme of the form $E(x)=g^x$ for some generator $g$ of an elliptic curve group.

Comment: What research have you done? What did you find?

Comment: This is relevant: https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/275 
And probably some stuff are linked in the intro

Comment: The first paper that addressed this question is [this one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/240.pdf)